# Calculate the total number of threads that are active from all the processes in Android

Tags: android

How can I get the total number of threads that are currently running on my Android device? Consider I want to display this information through an AOSP system application.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** − Create a new project in Android Studio, go to File ⇒ New Project and fill all required details to create a new project.

**Step 2** − Add the following code to res/layout/activity_main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the above code, we have taken textview. It contains information about the current thread count.

**Step 3** − Add the following code to src/MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   TextView textView;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
      textView.setText("Current thread: " + Thread.activeCount());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thread.activeCount() returns the number of active threads in the current thread's ThreadGroup. I need the count of all the active threads across the system.